# What's the difference in Github between fixing, resolving and closing and issue?

Tags: github, github-issues

Here in Github it refrences 3 ways to discuss a ticket:

https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue

- close
- resolve
- fix

I was wondering what the techincally differences are between these 3, they all sound very similar to me.

Comment: Well you can close or resolve something without fixing anything. In the same way something might get closed but not resolved, i.e. won't fix

Comment: How to use a web site is not a programming question.

Comment: @matt .... and definitely not a git question

Comment: ah really sorry, i thought there might be some special git terminology here and i wanted to use the correct one, i can't delete the question now sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The list you are quoting is not a list of options presented in a menu, it is a list of different ways of saying the same thing.

These are all just keywords which Github recognises when it looks at the description. Different people use different terms, so rather than forcing people to use (and remember) one preferred term, they include multiple possibilities.

The examples below the list use different keywords just for illustration. All the keywords are interchangeable.